# Removing table from schema.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I had a Location model in my app, but then I went a step back with Git, when I didn't create the model yet, then after quite a while working on another branch I realized that the model had gone nowhere, and it is still in my schema. I tried to get rid of it but it still pops out of nowhere, although there are no add location migration files in my app. What is the best way to get rid of it and clean up my schema.rb?

UPDATE 1

Running

rails destroy model location

Gives me

```
  invoke  active_record
  remove    /Users/denis/Desktop/migration/templates/create_table_migration.rb
  remove    app/models/location.rb
  invoke    test_unit
  remove      test/models/location_test.rb
  remove      test/fixtures/locations.yml
```

And I can run it for the indefinite amounts, it will always give the same result

Running this migration:

```
class DropLocationsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    drop_table :locations
  end
end
```

Gives 0 result, after rake db:migrate the Locations appear in my schema.rb again

UPDATE 2

```
rails db
SQLite version 3.7.12 2012-04-03 19:43:07
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> SELECT * FROM locations;
sqlite>
```

Comment: After running this migration if you do `rails db` and then in db prompt `SELECT * FROM locations;` what happens?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel nothing (updated question)

Comment: I just tried to reproduce and I had to first drop the table and then run `rails destroy model location`, otherwise it throws an error. When I first migrate db to drop the table, then run `rails destroy model…` and then run `rails c` I see in git diff that table was removed from schema. So I think you didn't see an exception somewhere. Try to re run it in order I did it.

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel I went with your ordering, recreated the migration and it worked! Can you make it into a separate answer so I can select it

Comment: I updated my existing answer!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to really really remove it you should prepare a migration to drop the table.

If you just remove the model ActiveRecord will still find the table in db (and that's probably why you're seeing it in `schema.rb` - if I am right that you mean file and not db schema)

EDIT:

So I tried to reproduce this, and as a result I ended up with following order of commands.

1. first drop the table (make a new migration with `drop_table :locations` and run it)
2. then run `rails destroy model location` (you will get an error if you destroy model first)
3. run `rails c` so Rails picks up the db change and updates `schema.rb`

Comment: yes, the file, exactly. What kind of migration are you talking about?

Comment: I guess the model and db table didn't create themselves, right? You wrote a Rails migration to create them. So now you need to create another one that will remove the table.

Comment: I'm really new at this so a helpful guide-link would be much appreciated

Comment: So how did you get the tables in the db in the first place?

Comment: I have updated my question with these details, please have a look

Comment: The migration is in this file? `/Users/denis/Desktop/migration/templates/create_table_migration.rb`

Comment: I am a bit stumbled, because I don't have this folder on my Desktop. My rails app is actually located elswere

Comment: I ran into the same problem, and found, strangely, that while there was no model or migration, the `rails destroy model` actually called remove on a migration from the past that was no longer there.

Answer (score 2):

run a migration like so

rake g migration DropLocations

This will create a migration file. Edit the migration file to look like so

class DropLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    drop_table :locations
  end
end

Run your migrations with rake db:migrate. This should drop the table from your schema.rb

Answer (score 2):

I find that it's easiest to use the Rails Console in solving this problem. Suppose you want to remove a 'comments' table from a blog application. You can do so by performing the following tasks from the command line (e.g., Terminal).

Step one:

```
$ rails console
```

Step two:

```
$ ActiveRecord::Migration.drop_table(:comments)
```

Step three:

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

Go check your schema.rb to see that the table was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove it. Run your migrations again.

Comment: did that - pops out back

Comment: You have to commit it for once & for all

Comment: git commit db/schema.rb -m "recommiting"

Comment: Nop. If I run rake db:migrate after re-commit Locations appear in schema.rb again